# Fresh install of Windows 10 on SSD, HDD permissions still playing up

Tags: windows, hard-drive, permissions

I have done a fresh install of Windows 10 on my SSD as the upgrade version was playing up. I was hoping I could just right-click on my HDD in My Computer, and give my new install Admin User Full Access to the files, but i'm having issues.

Here you can see my general folder structure on my (D)Drive which is my HDD
[image]

If I for example right click the "Users" folder, which is where all my media data is stored, I get the following users in the security tab:

[image]

I have no issues accessing that folder, but when I come to access the `Documents` folder, which is within the `Users` folder, I have to grant myself permission, which Windows does for me in this case. But when I look at the security tab of my `Documents` folder, I see an additional user, which is the email that my account uses, so why is that not in the security tab of the `Users` folder which I can access no problem!?

[image]